# Can we use boost libraries in a static dll file?

Tags: c++, boost, dll

I currently have a C++ dll file in which exported methods have been defined in the .def file.
I also have somewhat used boost shared ptr in the project and I am getting this error.

```
Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea.
```

Can anyone explain what this means. [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/boost-list/yTyBiY8PoO8) link discusses this issue but I still dont get it. Does this mean I should not use any boost library in my dll file ? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that your DLL uses the static runtime? Generally - especially when the program using it is also written in C++ - this is not a good idea.

Comment: Is your question why that's a bad idea, why you're getting the message, what you should do about it, or something else?

Comment: My question is why am I getting the message and how I can resolve it.

Comment: You cannot. C++ DLLs do not coexist with static runtimes. This is a fact of life in Microsoft's world. Accept it and move on.

Comment: @n.m. was that your answer to whether we can use boost with static dll libraries ?

Comment: Basically yes, though I answered to "how can I fix it". Well, if you wrap a C++ library in a C interface, you can use it with any kind of runtime, but then you don't have much of a C++ library left.